# PATCH/PUT not accepting multipart/form-data file uploads?

Tags: php, post, file-upload, patch, multipartform-data

Any idea why PATCH and PUT wouldn't be accepting multipart/form-data file uploads?

When I run `var_dump($_FILES)` it outputs `array(0) { }`. Any ideas why this is happening? If I POST the file, it works fine.

Below is an example of the request I am running.

Thanks in advance!

```
PUT /test.php HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__
Host: [redacted]
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.1.1 (Macintosh; OS X/10.10.2) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 17961

--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="default.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG


[IMAGE DATA]
--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__--
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When uploading files using a PUT request you don't use multipart/form-data. A PUT request is almost the same as a GET request. All you should be doing is putting the contents of the file in the body of the request. After that you can retrieve the file with the following code as explained in the php docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php):

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

Comment: I don't know how to get only input file from this example. My form submit input and input file together and all of them save in the file.ext.
If i use method post I can access input from $_POST['name'] and file from $_FILE['file']['name'] but this... how?