# Get file from form that is dynamically added

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

On my website, I have an slider with images. In the backend, the current slider images are displayed as well as a button that adds an input field, so I can upload new images for the slider.

The code to add the input field is done with some jQuery. When I click the button, the following Javascript function is being executed:

```
function addSliderImageEdit(){
    dataToAppend =
        "<li class='list-group-item'>" +
        "<div class='form-inline'>" +
        "<div class='input-group'>" +
            "<input type='file' id='slider-edit' class='slider-edit' name='slider-edit'/>"+
        "<span class='input-group-btn'>" +
        "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-remove-image-upload' type='button'>Verwijder afbeelding</button>" +
        "</span>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</li>";

    $('#btn-add-image-upload').on('click', function () {
        $(".list-group")
            .append(dataToAppend);
    });

    $('.list-group').on('click', '.btn-remove-image-upload', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
    })
}
```

The code works well and an input field with a remove button is being added.

The problem is that I can't access images that are uploaded with this dynamically added input field. When I use `Input::file()` or `Request::file('slider-edit')`, the result is always `null`.

I think it's because I don't use the Laravel Form Builder to create these dynamic input fields. I tried to change the Javascript code so that it uses the Laravel Form Builder, but it wouldn't work.

So, does someone know how I can access these files that are being uploaded with the dynamically added input field in Laravel?

Thanks in advance.

==================EDIT=================

My form starts with:

```
{!! Form::model($project, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['Backend\ProjectController@update', $project->id], 'files' => true]) !!}
```

The code that displays the current slider images:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p><strong>Huidige slider afbeeldingen</strong></p>

            <ul class="list-group sortable-images">

                {!! Form::text('order', '', ['id' => 'serialize_input']) !!}

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    {!! Form::button('Voeg afbeelding toe', ['id' => 'btn-add-image-upload', 'class' => 'btn
                    btn-default']) !!}
                </div>

                @foreach($images as $image)

                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <p style="display:none">{{ $image->id . ';'}}</p>

                    <img src="/images/sliders/{{ $image->image }}" class="img-responsive">

                    <div class="input-group">
                        {!! Form::text('image[' . $image->id . ']', $image->image, ['class' => 'file-caption-name form
                        form-control file-caption kv-fileinput-caption']) !!}
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-danger fileinput-remove fileinput-remove-button"
                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                                <span><span class="hidden-xs">Verwijder</span> {!! Form::checkbox('delete_image[' . $image->id . ']', $image->image) !!}</span>
                            </button>

                            <div tabindex="500" class="btn btn-success btn-file"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i> <span class="hidden-xs">Pick Image</span>
                                {!! Form::file('sliderimage[' . $image->id . ']')!!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                @endforeach

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And to close the form:

```
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I don't know if this is exactly what you were asking for, but this is the code where the dynamic generated code is being placed.

Comment: You need to show your form code there. Maybe form has no enctype="multipart/form-data" . Or other problems can be. Difficult to say without a form

Comment: Hint: use `$(this).closest('li').remove();` instead of all those parent()

Comment: @RomanGelembjuk I added a piece of code. I hope this is what you were talking about! And Yuri, thanks for the suggestion. I did not know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it's actually outside the code I provided, which I didn't expect, so my apologies for that.

The problem lies within this piece of code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   {!! Form::model($project, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['Backend\ProjectController@update', $project->id], 'files' => true]) !!}
```

My `Form::submit()` and `Form::close()` are found on the bottom of the page, but because the div is being closed earlier, the rest of the page inputs and textboxes didn't get send with the request.

So the code looked like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
       {!! Form::model($project, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['Backend\ProjectController@update', $project->id], 'files' => true]) !!}

       ...
       some input boxes
       ...
</div>

the input fields for the slider images

{!! Form::submit() !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And now, my code looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
       {!! Form::model($project, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['Backend\ProjectController@update', $project->id], 'files' => true]) !!}

       ...
       some input boxes
       ...


       the input fields for the slider images

       {!! Form::submit() !!}

       {!! Form::close() !!}

</div>
```

And now, the form correctly displays the uploaded files when I use `dd()`.

Feeling quite dumb now, because the problem was a simple misplaced brackets and it cost me a few days to find the error. Also, my code has a lot of divs and other tags, so that misplaced bracket didn't stick out. But thanks again for looking and trying to find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep using `patch` for some reason, then the files get passed through the body of the request in which case you won't be able to grab them from Laravel using the usual methods `Input::file()`.

You will need to use the methods described in [PATCH/PUT not accepting multipart/form-data file uploads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791057/patch-put-not-accepting-multipart-form-data-file-uploads) instead.

If you change it to `post`, it should work as is assuming there are no additional errors.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately, it didn't make any difference. But I just found the solution and posted it beneath this post.